# We are better than ever

Tags: comparative-constructions

When you mean "we (a couple) are in a better relationship than ever" by saying "We are better than ever", is "better" the comparative form of "good" or "well"?

In other words, to express that we're in a good relationship, which is correct?

> We are good.
>
> We are well.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this link here,](https://www.dictionary.com/e/comparatives-and-superlatives/) "better" is the comparative term for **both well and good.** However, it is important to note that well is an *adverb*,* whereas good is an *adjective.*

Hence, "We are good" is the correct sentence grammatically.

NOTE: [Well can also be an adjective, but the meaning is different.](https://www.google.com/search?q=well%20meaning&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN732IN732&oq=well%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1542j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  "Well" as an adverb is "in a good/satisfactory way", whereas is an adjective when referring to good health.

Comment: Hey! I'm getting downvoted, but I'm not sure why. :/